# Find greatest of three values in PHP

Tags: php

With three numbers, `$x`, `$y`, and `$z`, I use the following code to find the greatest and place it in `$c`. Is there a more efficient way to do this?

```
$a = $x;
$b = $y;
$c = $z;
if ($x > $z && $y <= $x) {
    $c = $x;
    $a = $z;
} elseif ($y > $z) {
    $c = $y;
    $b = $z;
}
```

Comment: Related: [PHP Type-Juggling and (strict) Greater/Lesser Than Comparisons](http://stackoverflow.com/q/15813490/367456)

Answer (score 30, accepted):

Probably the easiest way is `$c = max($x, $y, $z)`. See the documentation on [`max`<sup>*Docs*</sup>](http://php.net/max) for more information, it compares by the integer value of each parameter but will return the original parameter value.

Comment: Old q/a, I know, but <insert a mini-rant about PHP documentation here> as an explanation for why I wasn't aware of max() at the time.

Answer (score 12):

You can also use an array with max.

```
max(array($a, $b, $c));
```

if you need to

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php
$a=20;
$b=10;
$c=1;
if($a>$b && $a>$c)
{
echo "Greater value is a=".$a;
}
else if($b>$a && $b>$c)
{
echo "Greater value is b=".$b;
}
else if($c>$a && $c>$b)
{
echo "Greater value is c=".$c;
}
else
{
echo"Dont Enter Equal Values";
}
?>
```

Output:

```
Greater value is a=20
```

Answer (score -1):

If you want to Compare Three Variables. Compare two integers and get maximum of them by using `max()` function. Then compare the maximum with the third variable!

```php
$x = 1; $y = 2; $z = 3;
$maximum = max($x, $y);
$c = max($maximum, $z);
echo $c; //3
```

Also you could do it just in one line `max(max($x, $y), $z)`.