# PHP string number concatenation messed up

Tags: php, string, concatenation, operator-keyword, operator-precedence

I got some PHP code here:

```
<?php
    echo 'hello ' . 1 + 2 . '34';
?>
```

which outputs 234,

But when I add a number 11 before "hello":

```
<?php
    echo '11hello ' . 1 + 2 . '34';
?>
```

It outputs 1334 rather than 245 (which I expected it to). Why is that?

Comment: Why isn't any answer accepted?@JetLaggy seems to be new...accept a answer so that the thread would be closed and answerer  gain some reputation! ;) :)

Answer (score 17, accepted):

That's strange...

But

```
<?php
    echo '11hello ' . (1 + 2) . '34';
?>
```

*or*

```
<?php
    echo '11hello ', 1 + 2, '34';
?>
```

fixes the issue.

---

***UPDATE v1:***

I finally managed to get the proper answer:

`'hello'`  = `0` (contains no leading digits, so PHP assumes it is zero).

So `'hello' . 1 + 2` simplifies to `'hello1' + 2` is `2`. Because there aren't any leading digits in `'hello1'` it is zero too.

---

`'11hello '` = `11` (contains leading digits, so PHP assumes it is eleven).

So `'11hello ' . 1 + 2` simplifies to `'11hello 1' + 2` as `11 + 2` is `13`.

---

***UPDATE v2:***

From *[Strings](http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.types.string.php)*:

> The value is given by the initial portion of the string. If the string
> starts with valid numeric data, this will be the value used.
> Otherwise, the value will be 0 (zero). Valid numeric data is an
> optional sign, followed by one or more digits (optionally containing a
> decimal point), followed by an optional exponent. The exponent is an
> 'e' or 'E' followed by one or more digits.

Comment: Hi,man. thanks for the quick reply. 245 is what I expected it to output, but it showed 1334. I just don't understand why the precedence changed if I add number before hello string.

Comment: PHP very like to convert everything to numbers. Read [here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/15856770/2269749).

Comment: @CORRUPT Thanks a lot! A complete answer and easy to understand. Cheers~

Answer (score 6):

The dot operator has [the same precedence](http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.operators.precedence.php) as `+` and `-`, which can yield unexpected results.

That technically answers your question... if you want numbers to be treated as numbers during concatenation, just wrap them in parentheses.

```
<?php
    echo '11hello ' . (1 + 2) . '34';
?>
```

Comment: Cheers, this helps. I really should just stick to php manual. coz the one that I read earlier says concatenation has higher precedence than addition....  what a shame......

Comment: In PHP 8 "+" and "-" now take a higher precedence. So the problem is resolved.

Answer (score 5):

You have to use `()` in a mathematical operation:

```
echo 'hello ' . (1 + 2) . '34'; // output hello334
echo '11hello ' . (1 + 2) . '34'; // output 11hello334
```

Comment: Still, it does not explains why `php` ignores `concat` operator and typecast `string` to `int` while concating. Acting as sum, but not as concat.

Answer (score 1):

If you hate putting operators in between, assign them to a variable:

```
$var = 1 + 2;

echo 'hello ' . $var . '34';
```