# Infinite loading issue PHP

Tags: php, for-loop, foreach

Here's the code:

```
<?
$C1=array("a"=>1,"b"=>2);
$C2=array("z"=>1,"s"=>2);
$C3=array("x"=>1,"h"=>2);
$C4=array("a"=>1,"c"=>2);
$keywords=array("x","z","h");
for($i=2;$i<4;$i++)
{
    $i="C".$i;
    $array=$$i;
    foreach($keywords as $val)
    {
        if(isset($array[$val]))
        {
            echo $i." -> $val<br>";
        }
    }
}
?>
```

It should show:

```
C2 -> z
C3 -> x
C3 -> h
```

If i write `$i=2` instead of the `for()` loop it writes `C2 -> z`, as it should.

But I have to use the `for()` loop that generates an infinite loading.

Why? Where's the problem?

Comment: you're breaking the loop-variable (`$i="C".$i;`)...

Comment: Check out this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16851078/why-the-answer-is-15-here/16851120

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Inside the loop, you're reassigning `$i` variable with a string.  After that it doesn't pass the loop boundary check.  Instead, use another variable:

```
<?
$C1=array("a"=>1,"b"=>2);
$C2=array("z"=>1,"s"=>2);
$C3=array("x"=>1,"h"=>2);
$C4=array("a"=>1,"c"=>2);
$keywords=array("x","z","h");
for($i=2;$i<=4;$i++)
{
    $a="C".$i;
    $array=$$a;
    foreach($keywords as $val)
    {
        if(isset($array[$val]))
        {
            echo $a." -> $val<br>";
        }
    }
}
?>
```

In addition, it's worth noting that your loop would only run twice (for $i equal 2 and 3), as you're comparing `$i<4`.  So in my code I changed this to `$i<=4` to fix this.

Answer (score 1):

At first $i is a number and then $i++ increments as expected 
but then you change $i to "C".$i

so that $i="C2"
now i guess that ++ operator applied to C2 value  never makes it >4