# How can this if-statement evaluate to true?

Tags: php, if-statement

```
if ($opts['width'] == 'fs' || $opts['height'] == 'fs' || $opts['ratio'] == 'fs') {
    var_dump($opts); // result of this see bellow
}
```

Result of `var_dump($opts)` **inside** (!) if-statement:

```
array(3) {
   'width' => int(200)
   'height' => int(0)
   'ratio' => int(0)
}
```

How is this possible? None of the array's values is (stirng) fs?

Comment: Try using `===`! http://ideone.com/EpsAH2

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Because `0 == 'fs'`. See this **[conversion table](http://php.net/manual/en/types.comparisons.php)**.

PHP has the `===` operator to compare both value **and** type.

For a more extensive table: [Type-juggling and (strict) greater/lesser-than comparisons in PHP](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15813490/php-type-juggling-and-strict-greater-lesser-than-comparisons)

Comment: Thank you for the conversion table link. But in my opinion that's in someway weird. 0 should not evaluatue true to (string) 'fs'. Anyway, I've saved the link for the future!

Comment: @mcj: In PHP, if `A == B` and `B == C` it doesn't mean that `A == C`.