# Comparing numeric strings

Tags: php

From the question [Type-juggling and (strict) greater/lesser-than comparisons in PHP](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15813490/php-type-juggling-and-strict-greater-lesser-than-comparisons)

I know PHP interpret strings as numbers whenever it can.

```
"10" < "1a"  => 10 less than 1      expecting  false 
"1a" < "2"   => 1 less than 2       expecting  true
"10" > "2"   => 10 greater than 2   expecting  true
```

But in the case of `"10" < "1a"` php returns true.

I am not understanding the concept please help me to clarify it.

**Edit:**

But when I add `"10" + "1a"` it returns 11 that means php interprets "10" as 10 and "1a" as 1. Is that correct?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's easy `1a` is not numeric. So PHP compares `string(2)"10"` against `string(2)"1a"` and numbers are before alpha characters in the most text encoding tables (have a look at the [ASCII](http://www.asciitable.com/) or [UTF-8](http://www.fileformat.info/info/charset/UTF-8/list.htm) character tables).

So `1` of `10` is equals `1`of `1a` and `0` of `10` is lower than `a` of `1a`. That results in `10` is lower than `1a`.

Comment: I got it. But when adding it is another result. Please see my edit

Comment: Mathematic operations are another shoe that's true cause PHP can not add two strings but compare two strings. This is why PHP propably extract the numbers out of `1a` if you try to add it. **But you should never ever do something like that!** Even if PHP don't treat it with an error ;-). That's how you would add a pear in a bucket full of apples.

Answer (score 6):

A comes after 9. You can see this in this string, sorted from low to high.

```
0123456789abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz
```

So 10 is lower than 1a.

Comment: Nice and simple. Thanks

Answer (score 3):

If you want to be sure, that you comparing numbers, put (type) before variable:

```
(int)"10" < (int)"1a"
(int)"1a" < (int)"2"
(int)"10" > (int)"2"
```

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you first need to use regular expressions?

For example:

```
$str = '1a';
$str = preg_replace ("/[^0-9\s]/","", $str);
var_dump((int)$str); // int 1
```

Answer (score -1):

Read at [this link](https://www.php.net/types.comparisons) to get what happens when comparing value of two different data types.

Use [type juggling](http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.type-juggling.php) to compare values of two different data type.

```
(int)"10" < (int)"1a"  result will be false
(int)"1a" < (int)"2"  result will be true
```

Comment: That's not type juggling, that's type casting. Check the page you linked to, it's under a different heading. Type juggling is what PHP does automatically, type casting is when you tell it what to do explicitly using e.g. (int).